# unity シーンを移動しても変数を引き継ぐ方法

Tags: c#, unity3d

シーンを移動しても変数を引き継ぐ方法はありますか？？

例えば　二個のシーンがあるとします　（ショップとメイン）　
ショップで通貨を消費してアイテムを買ったとします。　その効果をメインに引き継ぐ
方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

static なオブジェクト／クラスを作成してそこで通貨やアイテムを管理させるのが簡単な方法です。

例えばこんなクラスを作ります。

```
class GameData {
    static int coins;
    static readonly List<int> items = new List<int>();

    public static bool BuyItem(int itemId) {
        // 購入処理
        if (coins >= 10) {
            // アイテムを買った
            items.Add(itemId);
            coins -= 10;
            return true;
        } else {
            // お金が足りない
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

このスクリプトをメインのシーンにでも追加しておけば、他のスクリプトからは

```
GameData.BuyItem(ItemId.hoge);
```

とか、シーンに関係なくいつでもアクセスできるようになります。

Comment: 上記のコードのままだと GameData.coins や GameData.items は直接は見られないので、public を付けるか、public static int GetCoins() なり取得関数を追加して必要な情報を得られるように拡張していきます。

Comment: 上記でコンパイルすると　cs(8,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name List1' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference　　と出てしまいます

Comment: "List1" って使ってないですが、どこか改変しました？

Comment: いえ、そのままコンパイルしました。Listのとこが存在しないとなっています。

Comment: 最初の方に using System.Collections.Generic; を追加してみてください

Comment: 回答いただいてから期間が開いてしまって申し訳ないのですが、いくつか質問よろしいでしょうか。　genericを入れたらコンパイルはできました。
itemIdのところは参照渡しをしているのですか？　
　ItemIdの意図はなんでしょうか？　　購入処理をしてcoinsから１０引いて
、itemsの中にあるリストにAdd(Itemid)とは？

Comment: itemId は int なので参照渡しではなく値渡しです。この辺はあくまで一例として捉えてもらって、アイテム管理／購入処理に関しては実装に合わせて変更してもらってよろしいでしょうか？要するにシーンに関係なく値や状態を保持するには staticにすれば簡単です、という回答です。